# watch ng-model inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
directive('myInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            type: '@',
            value: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/dc-input.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.disabled = attrs.hasOwnProperty('disabled');
            scope.required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required');
            scope.pattern = attrs.pattern || '.*';
        }
    };
});
```

with the following template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input-{{id}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10" ng-switch on="type">
        <textarea ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-model="value" class="form-control" id="input-{{id}}" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="required"></textarea>
        <input ng-switch-default type="{{type}}" ng-model="value" class="form-control" id="input-{{id}}" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="required" pattern="{{pattern}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is used by this form:

```
<form ng-controller="UserDetailsCtrl" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div ng-show="saved" class="alert alert-success">
        The user has been updated.
    </div>
    <my-input label="First name" value="user.firstName" id="firstName"></my-input>
    <my-input label="Last name" value="user.lastName" id="lastName"></my-input>
    <my-input label="Email" value="user.email" id="email" type="email" disabled></my-input>
    <my-input label="Password" value="user.password" id="password" type="password"></my-input>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Which has this controller:

```
controller('UserDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get({userId: $stateParams.id});
    /**
     * Update the current user in this scope.
     */
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.user);
        $scope.user.$update({userId: $scope.user.id}).then(function(results) {
            $scope.saved = true;
        });
    };
}).
```

The form is rendered fine, but when I click the `Save` button, the user values are never updated.

How can I use the updated values from within the myInput directive in the controller scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the basic problem. Your `ng-model` is a primitive and is only being bound in one direction...it will update if parent object is changed, but since it is primitive it does not carry reference to parent object...just value. Thus updating the primitive does not update parent object that it's original value came from

> Cardinal rule in angular...**always have a dot in ng-model**

Here's a solution that will pass the main `user` object to directive scope, as well as the property of that object to use for each input

```
<my-input id="firstName" model="user" field="firstName" label="First name"></my-input>
```

Now need to pass the  object from controller into the directive scope:

```
app.directive('myInput', function() {
    return {  
        scope: {
           /* other props*/
            field: '@',
            model:'='/* now have reference to parent object in scope*/
        },
       ......
    };
});
```

Then  in markup for an input will use `[]` notation in order to get our **dot** in:

```
<input  ng-model="model[field]".../>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/s2sUZOPw0en7oLotiCdF?p=preview)**</kbd>

In order to use angular validation you will likely have to `require` the `ngModel` controller in your directive or use nested form

Comment: Thanks! Great answer with a great example.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `ng-switch`.

`ng-switch` like `ng-repeat` creates a new scope that inherits from the parent.

That means that if you have let's say:

$scope.foo = "hello";

And then you have something like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo">
```

Inside a `ng-switch`. When you update `foo` it is going to create its own `foo` that hides/shadows the parent `foo`.

In other words, the input will show `hello` but when you modify it, a new `foo` is created hiding the parent one. That means that your parent one won't get updated (your problem).

That is not Angular.js issue, that is how Javascript works.

Normally you want to do a:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo.bar">
```

That way, you can play with the inheritance and instead of creating a new `foo` it will just update the `bar` on the parent.

Since that is not something you can do every time and maybe in your concrete use case you can't, the easy way is just to use `$parent`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.value">
```

That way inside your ng-switch you will use directly the parent `value`.

I highly recommend you to read this ASAP: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4D6Gk5fK7qdoh1mndzo?p=preview

Cheers.

Comment: `$parent` still tricky, if other directives like ng-repeat get in the middle, like turning OP directive into a JSON model and doing `<myinput ng-repeat..>`

Comment: @charlietfl Indeed. But works perfect for his use case and well, he needed help for his use case. Your example is good, I just avoided to pass the entire object to every input, but works good too :)

Comment: I like this answer and it works great, but I like the one of charlietfl slightly better.

Comment: agree...wasn't saying your solution wasn't valid, just noting that `$parent` solutions can break unexpectedly when new nesting level gets thrown in

Comment: That is the beauty of Angular, a lot of ways of doing stuff :) And in any case, bring tests, that will prevent any failure.